# Why doesn't Apache allow access to files outside the web root from within index.html?

Tags: linux, apache, web, file-permissions, configuration-files

I have the following organization to my project but am unable to access the related CSS and JavaScript files from within my HTML code, unless I create symbolic links from the file to my web root.

Is this normal behavior for Apache or does the problem lie elsewhere?

**If I remove the symbolic links and correct the path in my `src` attributes the content of those outside files becomes inaccessible.**

```
userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ tree
.
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── html
│   ├── code.js -> ../js/code.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── jquery-3.2.1.js -> ../libs/jquery-3.2.1.js
│   └── style.css -> ../css/style.css
├── js
│   └── code.js
└── libs
    └── jquery-3.2.1.js

4 directories, 7 files

userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ less html/index.html

<!doctype HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head><!-- head -->
   <body>
     <h1>LOCAL TESTING SITE..</h1>
   </body><!-- body -->
    <script src="./code.js"></script>
</html><!-- html -->

html/index.html (END)
```

**^ Works**

```
userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ tree
.
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── html
│   ├── index.html
├── js
│   └── code.js
└── libs
    └── jquery-3.2.1.js

4 directories, 4 files

userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ less html/index.html

<!doctype HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head><!-- head -->
   <body>
     <h1>LOCAL TESTING SITE..</h1>
   </body><!-- body -->
    <script src="../js/code.js"></script>
</html><!-- html -->

html/index.html (END)
```

**^ Does NOT Work**

```
userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ tree -p
.
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  css
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  style.css
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  html
│   ├── [lrwxrwxrwx]  code.js -> ../js/code.js
│   ├── [-rw-rw-r--]  index.html
│   ├── [lrwxrwxrwx]  jquery-3.2.1.js -> ../libs/jquery-3.2.1.js
│   └── [lrwxrwxrwx]  style.css -> ../css/style.css
├── [drwxrwxr-x]  js
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  code.js
└── [drwxrwxr-x]  libs
    └── [-rw-rw-r--]  jquery-3.2.1.js

4 directories, 7 files
```

**^ Permissions on files**

```
userName@hostName:/etc/apache2$ less sites-available/test.local.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin myEmail@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test/html
        ServerName test.local
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

sites-available/test.local.conf (END)
```

**^ Virtual Host Configuration**

```
userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ uname -v

#35~16.04.1-Ubuntu


userName@hostName:/var/www/test$ apache2 -v

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

**^ System Info**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Worse - I don't get information I need.  How could anyone hate another person so much and spitefully dowvote my questions too?  What the hell is the point of that?  Like I dd something to be punnished for? That's sick!

Comment: You'll reap what you sow sirs

Comment: I don't believe any on Stack Overflow hates you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache will not (by default) allow HTTP requests to access files outside (above) the root directory of the website for security reasons.

Your document root is set as: `DocumentRoot /var/www/test/html`, so **all files** (including non-HTML files) need to in this directory. Just because the directory is called `html`, don't be confused into thinking it should only contain HTML files.

#### Working directory structure

```
userName@hostName:/var/www/test/html$ tree
.
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── js
│   └── code.js
├── libs
│   └── jquery-3.2.1.js
└── index.html

3 directories, 4 files

userName@hostName:/var/www/test/html$ less index.html

<!doctype HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head><!-- head -->
   <body>
     <h1>LOCAL TESTING SITE..</h1>
   </body><!-- body -->
   <script src="js/code.js"></script>
</html><!-- html -->

index.html (END)
```

You'll see that all files are stored inside the `/html` directory or subdirectories of it. The HTML links to the JS and CSS files have been updated to refer to the correct file locations.

If Apache allowed files outside (above) the root directory to be accessed, you would run into *major* security issues.

For example, imagine if someone had a HTML file that did the following:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <a href="../../../var/private/supersecret.conf">link to secret config file</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

This would allow users to gain access to any random file they wanted on the server.